# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'block_bullet' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pygame

I was attempting to make a game using Pygame, when implementing a function where the character shoots a projectile on the space bar being pressed, I came across an error:

```
File "/File/Path/Game.py", line 58 in draw_window 
    for block_bullet in block_bullet:
File "/File/Path/Game.py", line 123, in <module>
    draw_window()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'block_bullet' referenced before assignment
```

I have viewed other questions attempting to find an answer but could not find a solution

Here is a google docs link to the code:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YPIv3hIKtbTSORd_e4yRCCP9gIo_tJL6kzhIQHiodLI/edit?usp=sharing

I would like the 'Blocky' character to shoot these 'block_bullets' when the spacebar is pressed

Comment: What have you tried and which answers have you looked at? Also, if you create a minimal example to reproduce the relevant error, you'll have a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [mcve].

Comment: Also, it is generally considered a better idea to post the code in the question, rather than as a link.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, any attempt to modify a variable within a function results in that variable being local to the function. In your `draw_window` function, the line of code `for block_bullet in block_bullet:` attempts to modify the `block_bullet` variable, which has the effect of referencing a local variable to which no value is assigned, producing that error.

You need to rename the first use of `block_bullet` in that function to some other name, resulting in the code `for individual_bullet in block_bullet: indivdual_bullet.draw(win)`. (Any name that is not already used elsewhere in your program could work to replace `individual_bullet` in my example.)